# Fire an event while the mouse is down within my box 2d collider in Unity

Tags: unity

The method `OnMouseDown()` is called **once** when the mouse presses my box 2d collider.

Is there a method that keeps firing while the mouse is **still holding the button down inside the collider**? Something like `WhileMouseDown()`.

I could use `Input.GetMouseButton(0)` in the `Update()` method. However, this does not check if the mouse is pressing the collider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a combination of both `OnMouseDown` and [`OnMouseOver`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseOver.html):

> OnMouseOver is called every frame while the mouse is over the GUIElement or Collider.

You might want to set something like `bool mouseIsBeingHeld = true;` to track this and change it when [`OnMouseUp`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseUp.html) or [`OnMouseExit`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseExit.html) happens.

---

If you'd ever also want to just use `Input.GetMouseButton(0)`, the other way to see if a Collider2D is being hovered over is via [Collider2D.OverlapPoint](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OverlapPoint.html).